# Sphinx + MySQL, Not getting any results on select query

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, set, sphinx

I am currently investigating how to integrate sphinx on an existing website.

I am working for a customer who rents holiday homes. They have a website where customer can online make a reservation. On their front page they have a search engine which searches all their homes (20k) and orders them on various fields. In the past we did an MySQL query for every search. Right now the database has grown allot which make the query's allow slower then in the past. 
For this reason we are investigating on how to improve the search engine. I am currently working with sphinx to see if it will work out for us.

I have Sphinx installed and have the following source and index:

```
source huisjesSource
{
  type = mysql
  sql_host = localhost
  sql_user = user
  sql_pass = password
  sql_db = database

   sql_query= SELECT a.huis_id as huis_id, a.huis_code as huis_code, a.land_code,    a.regi_code, a.huis_naam, a.huis_plaats,a.multimedia,a.foto_a, a.foto_w,a.foto_a_full, a.foto_w_full, a.huis_van, a.huis_tm, a.hd, a.a_hd, st,a.sl, a.beds, a.bathr, a.baths,a.airport, a.huis_enqe_vr13_aantal, a.huis_enqe_vr13_punten, a.huis_longitude, a.huis_latitude, a.huis_catering_verplicht, 1w_min, 1w_max, 2w_min, 2w_max, 3w_min, 3w_max, wk_min, wk_max, lw_min, lw_max, mw_min, mw_max, age,(CASE WHEN vz200p239 = '1' or vz238 = '1' or vz235 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as relax,ph.plaatsnaam as hplaats,ph.hplaatsid,ps.subplaatsid,ps.plaatsnaam as splaats,ty20,ty30,ty40,ty50,ty60,ty70,ty90,ty160,becdir,huis_hbes_small, a.regi_oms_nl as regi_oms \
   FROM as_search a \
   left join bv_myisam.huis_plaats hpl on a.huis_code = hpl.huis_code \
   left join bv_myisam.plaatsen_head ph on hpl.hplaatsid = ph.hplaatsid and ph.lang = 'nl' \
   left join bv_myisam.plaatsen_sub ps on hpl.subplaatsid = ps.subplaatsid and hpl.subplaatsid != 'null' and ps.lang = 'nl' \
   left join huis_oms o on a.huis_code = o.huis_code AND o.lang = 'nl' \
   inner join huis_sort so on a.huis_code = so.huis_code \
   inner join bbpr_n b on a.huis_code = b.huis_code \
   WHERE a.avail = '1' AND a.demo = '0' AND a.bvdir = '1' \
   GROUP BY a.huis_code 

   # (not needed) sql_attr_uint = huis_id # int(11)
   sql_attr_string = huis_code # varchar(14)
   sql_attr_string = land_code # char(2)
   sql_attr_string = regi_code # varchar(10)
   sql_attr_string = huis_naam # varchar(50)
   sql_attr_string = huis_plaats # varchar(40)
   sql_attr_bool = multimedia # enum('1','0')
   sql_attr_string = foto_a # varchar(90)
   sql_attr_string = foto_w # varchar(90)
   sql_attr_string = foto_a_full # varchar(90)
   sql_attr_string = foto_w_full # varchar(90)
   sql_attr_uint = huis_van # tinyint(4)
   sql_attr_uint = huis_tm # tinyint(4)
   sql_attr_string = hd # char(1)
   sql_attr_uint = a_hd # tinyint(4)
   sql_attr_string = st # char(1)
   sql_attr_uint = sl # tinyint(3) unsigned
   sql_attr_uint = beds # tinyint(3) unsigned
   sql_attr_uint = bathr # tinyint(3) unsigned
   sql_attr_uint = baths # tinyint(3) unsigned
   sql_attr_string = airport # char(3)
   sql_attr_uint = huis_enqe_vr13_aantal # smallint(6)
   sql_attr_uint = huis_enqe_vr13_punten # smallint(6)
   sql_attr_float = huis_longitude # double(8,5)
   sql_attr_float = huis_latitude # double(8,5)
   sql_attr_bool = huis_catering_verplicht # enum(0,1)
   sql_attr_float = 1w_min # decimal(8,2)
   sql_attr_float = 1w_max # decimal(8,2)
   sql_attr_float = 2w_min # decimal(8,2)
   sql_attr_float = 2w_max # decimal(8,2)
   sql_attr_float = 3w_min # decimal(8,2)
   sql_attr_float = 3w_max # decimal(8,2)
   sql_attr_float = wk_min # decimal(8,2)
   sql_attr_float = wk_max # decimal(8,2)
   sql_attr_float = lw_min # decimal(8,2)
   sql_attr_float = lw_max # decimal(8,2)
   sql_attr_float = mw_min # decimal(8,2)
   sql_attr_float = mw_max # decimal(8,2)
   sql_attr_uint = age # tinyint(3) unsigned
   sql_attr_uint = relax # boolean
   sql_attr_string = hplaats # varchar(100)
   sql_attr_uint = hplaatsid # int(11)
   sql_attr_uint = subplaatsid # int(11)
   sql_attr_string = splaats # varchar(100)
   sql_attr_bool = ty20 # enum(1,0)
   sql_attr_bool = ty30 # enum(1,0)
   sql_attr_bool = ty40 # enum(1,0)
   sql_attr_bool = ty50 # enum(1,0)
   sql_attr_bool = ty60 # enum(1,0)
   sql_attr_bool = ty70 # enum(1,0)
   sql_attr_bool = ty90 # enum(1,0)
   sql_attr_bool = ty160 # enum(1,0)
   sql_attr_bool = becdir # enum(0,1)
   sql_attr_string = huis_hbes_small # varchar(2000)
   sql_attr_string = regi_oms # varchar(50)

   }

   #############################################################################
   ## index definition
   #############################################################################

   index huisjesIndex
   {
     type = plain
     source = huisjesSource
     path = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/huisjes
     charset_type = utf-8
     preopen = 1
   }
```

The index is creating fine:

```
# indexer --all
Sphinx 2.0.4-release (r3135)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'huisjesIndex'...
collected 17059 docs, 0.0 MB
total 17059 docs, 0 bytes
total 98.422 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 173.32 docs/sec
total 1 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 27 writes, 0.008 sec, 312.9 kb/call avg, 0.3 msec/call avg

# indextool --check huisjesIndex
Sphinx 2.0.4-release (r3135)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
checking index 'huisjesIndex'...
checking dictionary...
checking data...
checking kill-list...
check passed, 0.0 sec elapsed
```

But when I do a SELECT * FROM huisjesIndex I get an empty set, but there should be more then 17k records. Am I doing something wrong?

```
# mysql -h localhost -P 9306 --protocol=tcp
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 2.0.4-release (r3135)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SELECT * FROM huisjesIndex;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: My first reaction was that you don't select a database in the MySQL client, but I think it should give an error then, so there might be something else going on. Still worth to check prolly :)

Answer (score 0):

I havent checked percisely, but it looks like you've defined ALL your columns from the sql_query as **Attributes**.

Sphinx does not like that. Its a text search engine, so it expects some full-text **Fields**.

A simple solution (if you really do want all those attributes), is to use sql_field_string to make at least one of your columns a field as well as an Attribute.

---

The other odity, but might well just work anyway, is you are using a.huis_id as the document_id, but grouping a.huis_code. If they are not a 1:1 mapping (and unique) then you will run into issues. I think its more usual to group by the document_id.